# How can I remove points from a list which are close to points in another list by some distance

Tags: python, list, filtering, coordinates, euclidean-distance

I have 2 lists of coordinates of points in an image.

Say,

```
List1 = [[2,3],[4,5],[10,20],[45,60]]
List2 = [[100,50],[65,48],[58,32],[98,45]...............[655,254],[232,545]]

dist = 20
```

`List1` would have 5 or 6 elements.
`List2` could have more than 1000 elements.

I want to generate a `list3` in which I have only the coordinates from `List2` whose euclidean distance from all the points in `List1` is more than `dist=20`.

Basically my aim is to remove all points from `List2` which are near to points in `List1` by some distance.

Currently, I am doing something like this

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def newlist(list1, list2, dist):
    edist = cdist(list2, list1)
    highvalues = edist > dist
    edist[highvalues] = 0
    edist[~highvalues] = 1
    indx = edist.sum(axis=1)
    list3 = [list2[i] for i, e in enumerate(indx) if e == 0]

    return list3
```

Runtime: 52us

Comment: 1. loop through items of list 2 | 2. within first loop, loop through items of list 1 and use numpy.linalg.norm() to calculate distance | 3. if all match append item of list 1 to three

Answer (score 2):

```
List3= [p for p in List2 if all(cdist(i,p)>20 for i in List1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

simply for cal euclidean distance you must import `euclidean` from `scipy.spatial.distance`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
new_list=[]
for i in List2:
    for j in List1:
        if euclidean(i,j)>20:
            continue        
    new_list.append(i)
```

Comment: I'd use tuples (should be more memory efficient for large lists, and you might apply set()-operations to it quite easily: ```new_list=[tuple(i) for i in List2 for j in List1 if euclidean(i,j)>20 ]```

Comment: you are right but maybe the user need a list for coordinates ? and need to use them in elsewhere !

Comment: @Kasra I believe it would take more time than my solution. I will be running on 1000s of lists. Anyway we can avoid the loops ?

Comment: for find the time of tow code try `time python file_name.py` in terminal and see the time of both and give me the result too ! thanks

Comment: I used %timeit in ipython   
For my method : 52 us  
For this method : 400us

Comment: ok thanks so edit my answer and add your answer too ! also write the run time of both !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using inefficient for-loops, one can use [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) in NumPy with [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

points = np.array([[0,1], [2,0], [4,5], [6,7], [9,9], [8,10]])
reference = np.array([[0,0], [10,10]])
distance = 3

filtered_points = points[np.all(cdist(points, reference) >= distance, axis=1)]
print(filtered_points)
# array([[4, 5],
#        [6, 7]])
```

Note that you can also change Euclidian metric to any other one. See [docs on `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) for details. For example for Manhattan distance one would write `cdist(points, reference, metric='cityblock')` instead.